# How can I keep text highlighting after pasting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small markdown editor

## [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t4ro53v8/4/)

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="txtarea">this is a **test**</textarea>
<button data-marker="**">Bold (toggle)</button>
<button data-marker="~~">Strike through (toggle)</button>
<button data-marker="*">Italics (toggle)</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function toggleMarker(marker, el) {
    var markerLength = marker.length;
    var startPos, endPos, selection, range;

    if (document.selection != undefined) { // IE
        el.focus();
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        selection = range.text;
    } else if (el.selectionStart != undefined) { // Firefox
        startPos = el.selectionStart;
        endPos   = el.selectionEnd;
        selection = el.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
    }
    
    if (!selection.length){
            return;
    }
    
    
    
    if (el.value.substring(startPos-markerLength,startPos) === marker
            && el.value.substring(endPos,endPos+markerLength) === marker
    ){
            el.value = el.value.substring(0,startPos-markerLength) +
                                selection + 
                  el.value.substring(endPos+markerLength);
    }
    else{
            el.value = el.value.substring(0,startPos) + marker + 
                                selection + marker + el.value.substring(endPos);
    }
    
}

$(document).on('mousedown', 'button', function(e) {
  toggleMarker( $(this).data('marker'), $('#txtarea').get(0) ).text;
});
```

Now I need to keep the highlighting of pasted text. How can I do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse

Comment: @Thomas Thank you. But I saw that before asking, and I really cannot use it for my case.

Comment: If you already saw something similar beforehand, you should mention that upfront. And even now that you have done that, you still fail to mention why you “cannot use it.”

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/medinasod/pen/GoOrwq

JS:

```
var markerLength,
    startPos,
    endPos,
    selection,
    range;

function selectText(startPos, endPos, markerLength, marker) {
    mytxtarea = document.getElementById("txtarea");

          window.setTimeout(function() {       
          if  (mytxtarea.value.substring(startPos-markerLength,startPos) === marker && mytxtarea.value.substring(endPos,endPos+markerLength) === marker) {
              mytxtarea.setSelectionRange(startPos+markerLength, endPos+markerLength);
            } else {
              mytxtarea.setSelectionRange(startPos+markerLength, endPos+markerLength);
            }
        }, 0);

}

function toggleMarker(marker, el) {
markerLength = marker.length;
    if (document.selection != undefined) { // IE
        el.focus();
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        selection = range.text;
    } else if (el.selectionStart != undefined) { // Firefox
        startPos = el.selectionStart;
        endPos   = el.selectionEnd;
        selection = el.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
    }

    if (!selection.length){
            return;
    }



    if (el.value.substring(startPos-markerLength,startPos) === marker
            && el.value.substring(endPos,endPos+markerLength) === marker
    ){
            el.value = el.value.substring(0,startPos-markerLength) +
                                selection + 
                  el.value.substring(endPos+markerLength);
    }
    else{
            el.value = el.value.substring(0,startPos) + marker + 
                                selection + marker + el.value.substring(endPos);
    }
  selectText(startPos, endPos, markerLength, marker);    
}

$(document).on('mousedown', 'button', function(e) {
  toggleMarker( $(this).data('marker'), document.getElementById('txtarea'));
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="txtarea">this is a test</textarea>
<button data-marker="**">Bold (toggle)</button>
<button data-marker="~~">Strike through (toggle)</button>
<button data-marker="*">Italics (toggle)</button>
```

Comment: My answer is a bit rough, but I believe it solves the specific question you asked. I would welcome any input on how to improve it.